# Dynamically created html table data not showing in order as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

```js
function CreateWeakHeader(name) {

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.classList.add("cal-usersheader");
  td.style.color = "#000";
  td.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";
  td.style.padding = "0px";
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));

  tr.appendChild(td);


  var thh = document.createElement('td');
  thh.colSpan = "31";
  thh.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
  thh.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";
  tr.appendChild(thh);

  return tr;

}

function htmlTable(data, columns) {
  var header = document.createElement("div");
  header.classList.add("table-responsive");

  var header2 = document.createElement("div");
  header2.id = "calplaceholder";

  header.appendChild(header2);

  var header3 = document.createElement("div");
  header3.classList.add("cal-sectionDiv");

  header2.appendChild(header3);




  if ((!columns) || columns.length == 0) {
    columns = Object.keys(data[0]);
  }



  var tbe = document.createElement('table');
  tbe.classList.add("table", "table-striped", "table-bordered");
  var thead = document.createElement('thead');
  thead.classList.add("cal-thead");
  tbe.appendChild(thead);

  var tre = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var the = document.createElement('th');
    the.classList.add("cal-toprow");
    the.textContent = columns[i];
    tre.appendChild(the);
  }

  thead.appendChild(tre);

  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  tbody.classList.add("cal-tbody");

  tbe.appendChild(tbody);
  var week = 0;
  //tbody.appendChild(CreateWeakHeader("Week " + week));

  var tre = document.createElement('tr');

  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {


    if (j % 7 == 0) {
      week++;
      tbody.appendChild(CreateWeakHeader("Week " + week));





    }
    var thead = document.createElement('td');
    thead.classList.add("ui-droppable");


    thead.appendChild(data[j]);
    tre.appendChild(thead);


    tbody.appendChild(tre);





  }




  header3.appendChild(tbe);
  document.body.appendChild(header);


}

$("#tb").click(function() {
  var header = document.createElement("div");
  header.innerHTML = "test";
  var d = [header, header, header, header, header, header, header, header];
  htmlTable(d, days);


});
var days = ['Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag'];
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="tb">CreateTable</button>
```

I'm trying to order the data that I get from my server to match the columns of my table.
My table columns are days from Monday to Sunday. When my data has more than 7items it needs to separate with another td. The td shows me week 1 and when my data has more than 7 items it needs to separate again that shows week 2 etc.

**Update**

Im now using a snipped verdion of my code.
Hope someone can help me out with this.
Thank you

Comment: The data you're passing to `htmlTable` is a little odd; two `div` elements? It would be nice if you could share a [mre] with us; just enough code that we can run it for ourselves. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm now using a snipped version of my code, hopley its more helpful now. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things going on in the code that are problematic.

1. An attempt to add the table cells to the row, and the row to the table, was made on each iteration of the `for` loop. That would have produced a lot of rows with single cells had it worked.
2. It didn't work because there was only ever a single instance of `tre`, the row variable. So that meant the line `tbody.appendChild(tre);` did nothing, since `appendChild` won't append an element that already has a parent element.
3. Because your `data` was an array of references to `HTMLElement`s with parents, appending them using `appendChild` did nothing for the same reason.

I've amended the code below to take care of all of these situations.

Firstly, the code will append a clone of the data to the cell if it's an `HTMLElement`. I expect in your real code you won't need this, but for this example, why not? It then appends the cell to the row and continues to the next data element.

Secondly, when the data iterator is at 7, before it appends the "Week N" header, it appends a clone of the row, if it has cells on it.

Finally, after appending the clone of the row, the code will reset the row variable to a new instance of a `tr` element, with no cells.

I also made some variable name and formatting changes to your code just so I could more easily work with it.

```js
function CreateWeakHeader(name) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.classList.add("cal-usersheader");
  td.style.color = "#000";
  td.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";
  td.style.padding = "0px";
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  tr.appendChild(td);

  var thh = document.createElement('td');
  thh.colSpan = "6"; // "31"; Why 31? A week has 7 days...
  thh.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
  thh.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";
  tr.appendChild(thh);

  return tr;
}

function htmlTable(data, columns) {
  var header = document.createElement("div");
  header.classList.add("table-responsive");

  var header2 = document.createElement("div");
  header2.id = "calplaceholder";
  header.appendChild(header2);

  var header3 = document.createElement("div");
  header3.classList.add("cal-sectionDiv");
  header2.appendChild(header3);

  if ((!columns) || columns.length == 0) {
    columns = Object.keys(data[0]);
  }

  var tbe = document.createElement('table');
  tbe.classList.add("table", "table-striped", "table-bordered");
  var thead = document.createElement('thead');
  thead.classList.add("cal-thead");
  tbe.appendChild(thead);

  var tre = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var the = document.createElement('th');
    the.classList.add("cal-toprow");
    the.textContent = columns[i];
    tre.appendChild(the);
  }

  thead.appendChild(tre);

  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  tbody.classList.add("cal-tbody");
  tbe.appendChild(tbody);

  var week = 0;
  //tbody.appendChild(CreateWeakHeader("Week " + week));

  var tre = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (j % 7 == 0) {
      week++;
      /* Major changes start here */
      // if the row has cells
      if (tre.querySelectorAll('td').length) {
        // clone and append to tbody
        tbody.appendChild(tre.cloneNode(true));
        // reset table row variable
        tre = document.createElement('tr');
      }
      // then append the Week header
      tbody.appendChild(CreateWeakHeader("Week " + week));
    }

    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.classList.add("ui-droppable");
    // Set the value of the cell to a clone of the data, if it's an HTMLElement
    // Otherwise, make it a text node.
    var value = data[j] instanceof HTMLElement ?
      data[j].cloneNode(true) :
      document.createTextNode(data[j]);
    td.appendChild(value);
    tre.appendChild(td);
  }
  // If the number of data elements is not evenly divisible by 7,
  // the remainder will be on the row variable, but not appended
  // to the tbody, so do that.
  if (tre.querySelectorAll('td').length) {
    tbody.appendChild(tre.cloneNode(true));
  }

  header3.appendChild(tbe);
  document.body.appendChild(header);
}

$("#tb").click(function() {
  var header = document.createElement("div");
  header.innerHTML = "test";
  var d = [header, header, header, header, header, header, header, header];
  htmlTable(d, days);
});
var days = ['Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag'];
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="tb">CreateTable</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this helpful changes... This major changes helped me alot thank you. Sometimes is hard to find where the problem is occured especally when using loops to create htmlelements.